# Office 365 Manifest for command-only Add-In

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, add-in

I have an add-in that just contains two ExecuteFunction commands.  In the generated manifest file from visual studio it contains the xml like:

```
<FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
        <DesktopSettings>
            <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:44351/MessageRead.html"/>
            <!--If you opt to include RequestedHeight, it must be between 32px to 450px, inclusive.-->
            <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
        </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
</FormSettings>
```

Since I don't have any UI in a task pane, why does it require this xml, and what would be the best practice here for my command-only add-in.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XML exists for compatibility with older Outlook clients and is required by the manifest schema.

As a best practice, since your add-in only uses add-in commands, set the [minimum requirement set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets) in the manifest to at least `1.3`, so the manifest and this URL won't be used by clients that don't support add-in commands.

```
<Requirements>
  <Sets>
    <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.3" />
  </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

Technically, this SourceLocation URL still appears in the payload of an [identity token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/inside-the-identity-token#identity-token-payload), so I would suggest setting it to a URL that's unique to your add-in.